# How to deploy selenium driven spiders on cloud

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, headless-browser, scrapyd

I use scrapyd to deploy and schedule my spiders on my local machine. 
The challenge I face now is deploying my spiders that executes with a headless browser.

I get two errors in my log file on scrapyd which are all related to not finding the webdriver in the project directory

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './chromedriver'

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

- Do headless browsers run on cloud ?
- Could the chromedriver have been dropped when i was deploying my project ?
- Is there a way to view my project files in scrapyd to be sure if the file still exists in project directory ?

Below is a copy of my code

```
# I'm using SeleniumRequest for my requests so this is the configuration is my settings file 


chrome_path='./chromedriver'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome' # Change to your browser name
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = chrome_path
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox

FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'
```

## Here is my spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time


class CovidngSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'covidng'
    #allowed_domains = ['covid19.ncdc.gov.ng']
    #start_urls = ['https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/']

def start_requests(self):
    yield SeleniumRequest(url ='https://covid19.ncdc.gov.ng/', wait_time = 3, screenshot = True, callback = self.parse)

def parse(self, response):



    driver = response.meta['driver']
    page_html = driver.page_source
    new_resp = Selector(text=page_html)

    databox = new_resp.xpath("//table[@id='custom3']/tbody/tr")

    for rows in databox:
        state = rows.xpath(".//td[1]/p/text()").get()
        total_cases = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/p/text()").get()
        active_cases = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/p/text()").get()
        discharged = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/p/text()").get()
        death = rows.xpath(".//td[5]/p/text()").get()

        yield {
            'State': state,
            'Total Cases': total_cases,
            'Active Cases': active_cases,
            'Discharged' : discharged,
            'Death': death
        }
```

Comment: first check if you have installed `chromedriver` because it is not part of `Selenium` and you have always install it separatelly. Second: use `/full/path/to/chromedriver` - system may run code in different folder then you expect and then relative path `./chromedriver` may direct to dirrefent place then you expect.

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer. it worked for me thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: check if you have installed `chromedriver` because it is not part of `Selenium` and you have always install it separatelly. (The same is with `geckodriver` if you use `Firefox`)

Second: use `/full/path/to/chromedriver` - system may run code in different folder then you expect and then relative path `./chromedriver` may direct to dirrefent place then you expect.